# H2 DB - Set time part in timestamp

Tags: timestamp, h2, timestampdiff

I'm writing a population script for H2 DB. I have a timestamp, this timestamp always has to be "yesterday", and it's time part has to be at 08:30. I tryed something like

`DATEADD('DAY', -1, TIMESTAMPADD('MINUTE', TIMESTAMPDIFF('MINUTE', CURRENT_TIME, '08:30:00'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))`

but H2 says that "Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "08:30:00"; SQL statement".

I don't want to do it in java, do you know some way to set time? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
select timestampadd('minute', 510, dateadd('day',-1, today()))
```

First we use [dateadd](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd) to shift back by '-1' 'day' from 'today()', then we use [timestampadd](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd) to shift forward by '+510' 'minute's (8:30).